# VersionPress database sync not working

Tags: wordpress, bitbucket

I'm trying to setup a dev+dev/staging/prod environment with Wordpress. I'm developing local on two Mac workstations (2 local developers) with MAMP. And I have a production server on Cloud. I installed the Wordpress site on my MAMP and cloned it on the other workstation and on cloud. I set GIT to not sync wp-config.php and I made it so that the two workstation and the prod site have the proper DB connection. All 3 site works. I can sync files with Bitbucket with no problem. I setup the VersionPress plugin on all 3 sites assigning the proper name: dev1, dev2 and production. On the Wordpress control panel I see that VersionPress is working, each clone can rollback changes. When I commit things in SourceTree/Bitbucket I see the database changes made by the other dev and the prod site, i.e. [VP] Published post "Test1". 
The problem is that the artcle made by Dev1 is not visible on Dev2 or Prod and vice versa. So if from my local MAMP, I log into Wordpress and go to Articles, I can't see the Test article made on the other cloned Wordpress site on our other workstation.

I should be 100% VersionPress compliant, and by the way in the VersionPress setup screen I had all check marked as good with the grey "V" icon.

Am I missing something?

Note: after installing VersionPress a lot of new .git and .gitignore were automatically populated, I guess that's okay, but I haven't touch them.

Other nore: VersionPress is amazing, for those who don't know it I strongly recommend it: https://versionpress.net/ I can't wait to have it 100% functional...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clone the sites using VersionPress, specifically its [`wp vp clone` command](https://docs.versionpress.net/en/sync/cloning). Then, you need to push and pull between environments using [the other WP-CLI commands](https://docs.versionpress.net/en/feature-focus/wp-cli), `wp vp push` and `wp vp pull`.

The syncing will not work if you installed VersionPress separately on three already existing clones of a site.

Comment: Hi Borek and thank you. I'll give it a try. Question: the site I need to version is on a remote/production server. I copied files and DB into my local MAMP manually (no wp vp clone). Do I need to install WP-CLI on the remote server and clone it from there and after download files and DB on my local environment?

Comment: Cloned the site with wp vp clone. I see database updates. I was hoping to be able to do everything with SourceTree, so far the only way to see changes was by using wp vp push / pull. Strange thing is that when I run the command wp vp clone I had a completely new version of the site, but apperently using the same DB, is it okay? So basically in wp-config for both site I had the same local DB, although changing thing on one site was not affecting the other one untill wp vp push / pull. I'm confused sorry.

Comment: @luke the separation is done by different table prefixes by default. I'd suggest chatting with us at https://gitter.im/versionpress/versionpress, should be better than this comment thread.